# What is the proper way to display content after a user is logged in?

Tags: php, html

When I have a user logged in, it redirects to this page:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])){
     include "content.php";
}
else {
  echo "You must be logged in.";
}
?>
```

What I just realized is that there is nothing stopping people from just going to the content.php page if they are logged out. Yeah, it won't show much, but what is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Do you want to hide any content in content.php if the user is logged out ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have things set up backwards. Instead of including `content.php` from the page that checks whether you're logged in, have `content.php` include the file that contains the check. That file should do something like:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) {
    die("You must be logged in.");
}
```

Another option is to keep your current structure, but put `content.php` outside the web root, so it can't be addressed directly with a URL.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you should not just have one file/function be the gateway to content being loaded. But you need to create a structure for how content is accessed.  So this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])){
  include "content.php";
}
else {
  echo "You must be logged in.";
}
?>
```

Should perhaps be tweaked & added to an `authentication.php` file that behaves like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])){
  echo "You must be logged in.";
  die();
}
?>
```

The logic is basically: Is this user logged in? Good, do whatever else needs to happen on the rest of the page. If not, echo a message blocking them & exit via `die()`. And then in `content.php`—and any other page you want restricted—you load `authentication.php` like so as the very first thing the page does:

```
<?php
require_once('authentication.php');
[...rest of `content.php` goes here...]
?>
```

And you always do that `require_once` on every page you want restricted.

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement, use something like this instead:

```
header("location:index.php");
```

Basically, you are saying if the user isn't logged in, redirect them to the homepage (or whatever page you specify, like a login page).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that part, but a user could just go to www.example.com/content.php and have the page shown and still not be logged in. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Cole - yes, I guess what I'm saying is that EVERY one of your php pages that you only want viewed by someone that's logged in, should include the `if not logged in, redirect to the login page` code at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to restrict access to any page is to `check` that access is granted for that user on that page. That means either adding

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])){

}
else {
  //header redirect;
}
```

to every page, or having a functions/config etc type of file that runs all the functions you need and include that header in there.

I'd recommend making something called init.php and including that in every page. Inside init.php you can have the code above, so you wont need to have session_start() and checking for login everytime. Keep in mind though if your functions such as data inside content.php is `dependent` on the user_id (meaning you have a custom page based on the user who logs on) then you have to include the init.php before you run any functions dependent on that.

For example you have a `functions.php` file

// get data from mysql db

function say_hi()
{
            $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'";
        $result = $db->query($sql);

            while ($rows =$chaptersResult->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $first_name = $rows['first_name'];
                    $last_name = $rows['last_name'];
                    $date_registered = $rows['date_registered'];

        }
          echo $first_name. " ".$last_name. "You registered on: ".$date_registered;
```

}

then on content.php you want to do something like  you wont be able to use that unless your inti.php (which will contain your $_SESSIONs for user ids and other stuff) is called BEFORE your functions.php.

for example

content.php

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';
require_once 'functions.php';

echo say_hi();
?>
```

The order does matter, and as you learn more you'll eventually have a config file for database connections, etc.